# formatting the orders within a list that are greater than a digit

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, indexing, format

I use the function `list_ .index(list_ )` to get the order of digits within `list_` like how `list_[0] = 14`. I want a function to format the `list_` and print the orders that are greater than 20. So the answer would be numbers = `1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10,11,13,18` within `list_[]` that are greater than 20.

```
list_ = [14, 25, 26, 21, 22, 17, 11, 23, 27, 18, 24, 28, 12, 29, 16, 19, 13, 10, 20, 15]
```

Comment: did you want it under a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_ = [14, 25, 26, 21, 22, 17, 11, 23, 27, 18, 24, 28, 12, 29, 16, 19, 13, 10, 20, 15]

for index,i in enumerate(list_):
    if i >= 20:
        print(index)
```

If you want it as a list

```
x = [index for index,i in enumerate(list_) if i >= 20]
print(x)

>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 18]
```